# Separate logging across different EE components (REST / EJB)

Tags: logging, log4j, ejb, java-ee-5

My purpose is to separate log4j configuration between REST and EJB in a JEE 5 web application (JBoss 5.1).

For **REST** module, I use the `ServletContextListener` interface:

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
     PropertyConfigurator.configure("logfile");
}
```

for **EJB** module, I'm using the `StartupBeanManagement` interface:

```
@Override
public void start() throws Exception {
    logger.info("starting configuration bean");
    final String env = System.getProperty("env");
    configureLog(logFilePrefix.replace("{0}", env));
}
```

However, if both modules are deployed on the same container, I can see log only only on dedicated **REST** log.

How I can separate logging between modules?

Answer (score 0):

Log4J holds its configuration at the classloader level.
If two JEE modules share a classloader, they will have a single Log4J configuration at runtime.

In order to separate logging between modules, you need to:

- Configure your application server to use separate classloaders for separate modules (not all application servers allow this); and
- Provide a separate Log4J configuration for every classloader.